# How to add new values to an array object using Vuex?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuex

I'm new with vuex, and I'm trying to store objects into an array called orders that have place on the store.js file.

I try to store the values from an object (e.g me.title) into an array that is in the store file by clicking on the button that triggers the method(triggerFunction), but I encountered two problems:

1 - On the console log, I observe that the only variable that is updated is state.order.title, the others remain as undefined (e.g orders.calories)

2 - Also, the state.orders array is empty and no value is pushed into state.orders, as programmed in the mutation.

app.vue

```
<template>
<p class="genric-btn primary circle text-uppercase" v-on:click="triggerFunction(me.title,me.description,me.price,me.calories)">add to cart</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            me:{
                title:"Hamburger",
                description:"Something here",
                price:"25",
                calories:"10"
            },
        }
  },
methods:{
   triggerFunction: function(title,description,price,calories){  
      this.$store.dispatch('triggerFunction',title,description,price,calories)
    },
}
</script>
```

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state:{
        order:{title:'',description:'',price:0,calories:0,qty:0},
        orders:[],
    },
    mutations:{
        triggerFunction: (state,title,description,price,calories) => {
            state.order.title = title,
            state.order.description = description,
            state.order.price = price,
            state.order.calories = calories
            state.order.qty = 1
            state.orders.push(state.order)
                        console.log(state.order)
                        console.log(state.orders)
        },
    },
    actions:{
        triggerFunction: (context,title,description,price,calories) => {
            context.commit('triggerFunction',title,description,price,calories)
        }
    },
})
```

Comment: Mutations only have 2 parameters first is the state and the second is the payload. You can use object instead of multiple params eg: `context.commit('triggerFunction', {title, description, price, calories})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Mutations and actions have 2 default parameters. First is the store's state, the second is the payload.
2. The store won't observe object key changes, in this case use [Vue.set](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set). But it's okay, if your store's order variable is not reactive.
3. You can use the data variables in the component, you don't have to pass it as a parameter. In case you are not using v-for.

**Here is the correct call of the action:**

```
<template>
    <p class="genric-btn primary circle text-uppercase" v-on:click="triggerFunction(me.title,me.description,me.price,me.calories)">add to cart</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data () {
        return {
             me:{
                title:"Hamburger",
                description:"Something here",
                price:"25",
                calories:"10"
            },
        }
  },
  methods:{
      triggerFunction: function(title,description,price,calories){  
      this.$store.dispatch('triggerFunction', {
          title: title,
          description: description, 
          price: price, 
          calories: calories
      }) // or ES6 if the value name equals with the key {title,description, price, calories}
    },
}
</script>
```

**Here is the correct store:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state:{
        order:{title:'',description:'',price:0,calories:0,qty:0},
        orders:[],
    },
    mutations:{
        triggerFunction: (state, payload) => {
            Vue.set(state.order, 'title', payload.title);
            Vue.set(state.order, 'description', payload.description);
            Vue.set(state.order, 'price', payload.price);
            Vue.set(state.order, 'calories', payload.calories);
            Vue.set(state.order, 'qty', 1);
            state.orders.push(state.order);
        },
    },
    actions:{
        triggerFunction: (context, payload) => {
            context.commit('triggerFunction', payload)
        }
    },
})
```

Comment: Excellent answer, you helped me to solve the problem. Thanks!